# Unrecognized statement type. (near "User" at position 4)

Tags: mariadb, comments, mysql-error-1064

> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Unrecognized statement type. (near "User" at position 4)
> SQL query:
>
> ----User Table Create---- CREATE TABLE User_( u_ID char(5) NOT NULL, u_NIC char(12) NOT NULL, u_f_name varchar(50), u_l_name varchar(50), u_email varchar(50), u_address varchar(255), u_dob date, u_role varchar(20), constraint user_PK primary key(u_ID), constraint Uu_IDChk check(u_ID like '[u/U][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'), )
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '----User Table Create----
> CREATE TABLE User_(
> u_ID char(5) NOT NULL,
> u_NIC ' at line 1

I'm getting this error while importing the database to phpmyadmin. How to fix this issue?

Code:

```
----User Table Create----
CREATE TABLE User_(
    u_ID char(5) NOT NULL,
    u_NIC char(12) NOT NULL,
    u_f_name varchar(50),
    u_l_name varchar(50),
    u_email varchar(50),
    u_address varchar(255),
    u_dob date,
    u_role varchar(20),

    constraint user_PK primary key(u_ID),
    constraint Uu_IDChk check(u_ID like '[u/U][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
);
```

Comment: I'm on my phone right now, but I think MariaDB might ***require*** a space after the `--` to be interpreted as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MariaDB comment syntax](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/comment-syntax/) requires a space after the initial `--` characters. It's a syntax error if you omit the space.

WRONG:

```
----User Table Create----
```

RIGHT:

```
-- User Table Create --
```